# Why is the line after the withContext blocked?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'd like to know how the line after the `withContext` (note: with `Dispatchers.IO` as its first parameter) is being blocked.

It appears that they are on a different thread but I'm wondering how coroutine executes them sequentially.

```
fun deleteAll() {
     viewModelScope.launch {
         Log.d("tag", "Outside withContext(start): " + Thread.currentThread().name)
         withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Log.d("tag", "Deleting....: " + Thread.currentThread().name)
            delay(3_000)
            Log.d("tag", "Done deleting.")
         }
         Log.d("tag", "Outside withContext(end): " + Thread.currentThread().name)
     }
}
```

Output:

```
ViewModel deleteAll returning
Outside withContext(start): main
Deleting....: DefaultDispatcher-worker-5
Done deleting.
Outside withContext(end): main
```

Comment: They're co-routines, that's what they're supposed to do? Where in earth does blocking come into it?

Comment: @BoristheSpider im expecting the log `Outside withContext(end): main` to output earlier

Comment: Why? It's an async await not magic. The outer coroutine gets parked, the main thread wanders off and does something useful. Once the inner coroutine finishes the outer coroutine resumes - once a thread is available to resume it.

Comment: So its like the whole coroutine block awaits line by line regardless of which context its in?

Comment: The coroutine block **async** awaits. Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `withContext`, you'll notice that it's a suspending function:

```
public suspend fun <T> withContext
```

Suspending functions are transformed into continuations by Kotlin compilers. Which you can think of as chain of callbacks.

So, you'll get something like this:

```
    fun a() {
        Log.d("tag", "Outside withContext(start): " + Thread.currentThread().name)
        fun b() {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                Log.d("tag", "Deleting....: " + Thread.currentThread().name)
                delay(3_000)
                Log.d("tag", "Done deleting.")
            }
            fun c() {
                Log.d("tag", "Outside withContext(end): " + Thread.currentThread().name)
            }
        }()
    }()
```

Now you can see more clearly, that `c()` cannot be executed, until `b()` has completed.

Another way to think of it is to look at the code of `withContext`:

```
...
  block.startCoroutineCancellable(coroutine, coroutine)
  coroutine.getResult()
}
```

Until `coroutine.getResults()` is completed, nothing else can happen.